# htaccess redirect root to subfolder - but keep other root subfolders beyond

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root, subdirectory

My server has several system folders and files by default. so for better overview I want to put my website in a subfolder like this:

www.domain.de/web/index.html

ALL links and website-related stuff is found in this subfolder "web". BUT the folder "web" should not be seen in the url!

I got this with these lines in my htaccess and it works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
```

**But now the problem:**
I also want other folder on my server to work. So www.domain.de/downloads/ should work, too. This folder is NOT in the subfolder "web". So if I write the direct url "www.domain.de/downloads" in my webbrowser, I don't want to get a redirect to "www.domain.de/web/downloads/", you know?

**Is there any solution? :)** 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use a RewriteCond to exclude your folder :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/download [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
```